# RegEx with 3 brackets and something in the middle

Tags: regex

I want to formulate a RegEx to find a pattern like this:

( ) ( ) (x)
or
( ) (x) ( )
or
(x) ( ) ( )

In words: find three open close brackets with something in the middle of one of them. I can do three regex patterns for that, dont need to be all in one.

That will stand for Operating Machines, Standby Machines and In Maintenance Machines. So, I'm looking for 3 different Regex formulas, to find each pattern. I did some improvement, but didn't go so far.
What I've tried:

```
\([^\(\r\n]*\)*\([^\(\r\n]*\)*\([^\(\r\n]*\)
\([^\(\r\n]\) \([^\(\r\n]*\) \([^\(\r\n]*\)
```

But didn't catch all my ocurrances.

I did some "test cases":

```
aaaaaaaaaa()xsadasds(X)dsadasdas()dsdadas
()()(x)
(y)    ()   ()
( ) (duo) ( )
( ) (x )  ( )
()()()
()dasdsa()dasdas()
(kwabanga)()()
```

I expect, in the following patterns to be find, i.e., having matches, respectively:

```
()(x)() => MATCH aaaaaaaaaa()xsadasds(X)dsadasdas()dsdadas
()()(x) => MATCH ()()(x)
(x)()() => MATCH (y)    ()   ()
()(x)() => MATCH ( ) (ANYTHING) ( )
()(x)() => MATCH ( ) (x )  ( )
dont find anything
dont find anything
(x)()() => MATCH (kwabanga)()()
```

Were I clear? I'm not sure how to proceed as I'm such a n00b with RegEx.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm going to use it in Excel VBA, with the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

Try this:

```
(?!(\(\s*\).*?){3})(\([^)]*\).*?){3}
```

*I checked above regex within a PCRE environment but I think it's VBA compatible too.*

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uB7yA9/4)

Comment: Nice! But I would consider using non-capture groups and I'm pretty sure you can leave `[^)]*?` as greedy (not that it makes any difference, just for personal style)

Comment: @skamazin Thanks. I modified lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly are alright with three separate regexes you could try something like these:

```
\(.+?\)\(.*?\)\(.*?\) # matches on (x)()()
\(.*?\)\(.+?\)\(.*?\) # matches on ()(x)() 
\(.*?\)\(.*?\)\(.+?\) # matches on ()()(x)
```